# SSLError - Certificate verify failed [first question answered, code still not working]

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import base64
import math
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define Login Auth
usrPass = "un:pass"
b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass)


# Input Direct Link
r = requests.get('https://URL...../api/incident?id=34219"', headers ={"Authorization": "Basic dHJhZ286eGVsb2M="  % b64Val}).text
print(r)
```

I'm new to Python. What I'm trying to do is web-scrape a page that is  an online/in-browser ticketing system. There is API documentation provided that details the 'Get Incident' function and spits out a full request URL and an Authorization Header that converts my login to a base64 code - the problem is that I can't figure out how to format this into my code so it actually works. Currently, I'm getting the 'Not all Arguments converted to STR' err, which I suspect is because I'm misusing '%' somewhere.

Thank you in advance for your help and if there is a better way to execute this code please let me know, I have a feeling there's a better way to go about this that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You need to precise where is your formatted code. Here, as `b64Val` seems to be a string, add `%s`.

```
r = requests.get('https://URL...../api/incident?id=34219"', headers={"Authorization": "Basic dHJhZ286eGVsb2M=%s"  % b64Val}).text
```

You can also use fstrings if you are in Python 3:

```
r = requests.get('https://URL...../api/incident?id=34219"', headers={"Authorization": f"Basic dHJhZ286eGVsb2M={b64Val}"}).text
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `%` operator is to replace special tokens such as `%s` in a string with actual values .  For example:

```
name = "Andy"
print("Hello %s" % name) # prints Hello Andy
```

You are getting this error because the string you're using does not have any `%s` tokens.

Comment: Thank you very much, that simple explanation helped me fix a few things!